# USB flash memory is not mounted after is connected?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, usb-flash-drive, mount

I have a Trancsend Jetflash TS2GJF210 USB drive. When I connect it to my old laptop (Dell Latitude D630) it is not mounted. `dmesg` shows following messages:

```
[108884.154796] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[108884.247600] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1307, idProduct=1169
[108884.247607] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=5, SerialNumber=3
[108884.247611] usb 2-2: Product: USB Mass Storage Device
[108884.247615] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: USBest Technology
[108884.247617] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[108884.248000] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[108884.248086] scsi10 : usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[108885.248226] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JetFlash TS2GJF210        0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[108885.248864] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[108885.250964] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] 4013568 512-byte logical blocks: (2.05 GB/1.91 GiB)
[108885.253748] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[108885.253756] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[108885.254776] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[108885.254783] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[108885.259941] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[108885.259951] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[108885.398908]  sdb: sdb1
[108885.403905] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[108885.403915] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[108885.403922] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[108885.403922] quiet_error: 126 callbacks suppressed
[108885.403922] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 501694
[108885.403922] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 501694
[108885.403922] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[108885.403922] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[108885.403922] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 1
[108885.403922] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 501695
[108885.403922] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 1
[108885.403922] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 1
[108885.403922] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 501695
```

and there is no `sdb` entry in `/dev` directory!

But if I disconnect the device and connect it to my another laptop (Dell Inspiron N4010) the device is mounted properly and `dmesg` shows:

```
[108884.154796] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[108884.247600] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1307, idProduct=1169
[108884.247607] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=5, SerialNumber=3
[108884.247611] usb 2-1.2: Product: USB Mass Storage Device
[108884.247615] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: USBest Technology
[108884.247617] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[108884.248000] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[108884.248086] scsi22 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[108885.248226] scsi 22:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JetFlash TS2GJF210        0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[108885.248864] sd 22:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[108885.250964] sd 22:0:0:0: [sdb] 4013568 512-byte logical blocks: (2.05 GB/1.91 GiB)
[108885.253748] sd 22:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[108885.253756] sd 22:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[108885.254776] sd 22:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[108885.254783] sd 22:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[108885.259941] sd 22:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[108885.259951] sd 22:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[108885.398908]  sdb: sdb1
[108885.403905] sd 22:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[108885.403915] sd 22:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[108885.403922] sd 22:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[108886.072068] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
```

I tired many times connecting it to working laptop (N4010) and then removing after eject (safely remove) and reconnecting to D630. I even run `fsck` on working laptop for this device. But the result is same: it is not mounted on D630 laptop.

Before this problem occurs (a few minutes ago) the flash drive was working properly on both devices, but now it is mounted and works only on N4010.

Both laptops have Ubuntu 13.10, N4010 is upgraded from Ubuntu 13.04 and is updated and D630 has a fresh installation of Ubunut 13.10.

I need to know why this problem occurred and how to solve it.

Comment: System time brackets ([108885:uuuuuu]) in first `dmesg` output code is copied and pasted from second one and is not real. because my D630 (problematic) laptop has no Internet connection and it takes too much time to type manually every [ssssss.uuuuuu] time stamp. But other parts are exactly same as what `dmesg` shows on D630 (problematic) laptop.